# Easy way to do this in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a BxNxL array, M. In other words, M is composed of B NxL matrices. In addition, I have a LxB column vector, Q. Is there any easy way (without for loops) to broadcast (sum) the ith column of Q to the ith matrix in M?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is very broad at the moment, and may be closed. Please provide the code you have written so far for this, and provide **specific** issues you are having with the code. Also, provide some example inputs and outputs. You must show that your have researched this problem to some extent, and attempted to write your own code, as this is not a code-writing service.

Comment: "LXB column vector, Q"? a column vector only has 1 column not B columns, am I missing something here? Also how can you broadcast a column to a matrix without running into dimensionality related issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your iterative code would be?

```
for i in range(...):    
    res[i,:,:] = M[i,:,:] + Q[:,i]    # NxL + L
```

with the whole array

```
res = M + Q.T[:,None,:]     # BxNxL  + (Bx1xL)
```

(I wrote this without a test example, so there might an error, but the basic idea should be right)